# Prove that the set of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ and so is closed under addition

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, invariant-subspace

I'm pretty confused about how to prove that it is closed under addition.

The way I'm thinking about this is probably very wrong, but I will describe it so that you can appoint where I did got it wrong.

The sum of two continuous real-valued functions on the interval of [0,1] won't necessarily result in a continuous real-valued function on the interval of [0,1], because the sum of two function whose results are 0.8(which is inside the interval established) and 0.9(which is  inside the interval established) will return 1.7 right? which is clearly out of the established interval, and that shows us that it isn't closed under addition, and so should no be considered a subspace right?

So, what did I miss?

Comment: "On the interval $[0,1]$" means that the functions are *defined* on $[0,1]$, not that they take their values in $[0,1]$.

Comment: You are confusing the domain with the range. Continuous functions  here take all real values and sum of continuous functions is continuous.

Comment: And the expression $\ \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}\ $ denotes the set of *all* functions from $\ [0,1]\ $ into $\ \mathbb{R}\ $.

Comment: Yeaah, It makes total sense. So that means that for it to be closed under addition, I just need to prove that the sum of two real-valued continuous functions in the interval of [0,1] still a real-valued continuous function in the interval of [0,1] right?

Comment: @IsraelCoêlho Yes, indeed.